# How to structure this async function to get a synchronous response

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, fetch

Here's some example code I have:

```js
async function getAppState() {
  return {
    appState: {
      someBar: false
    }
  },
  async function req() {
    const resp = await fetch("https://www.example.com/script.php", {
      method: 'GET',
    })
    this.appState.someBar = await resp.json();
  }
}
let foo = await getAppState();
console.log(foo)
```

I want to be able to get `appState` populated and pass it as an argument to `console.log` as in my example above. Clearly what I am doing does not work. I am attempting to show that I want to run `getAppState()` in a synchronous fashion so that I can get the result of the `fetch()` invocation into `console.log` after the function is invoked. What is the correct way to structure this code to do that?

Comment: your code is malformed - your `getAppState` function returns the `req` function

Comment: You're never calling that `req` function. Why did you even define that helper function?

Comment: An `async function` will never give you a synchronous response. You can however write it to wait for the right stuff in sequence before giving a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAppState()` doesn't need to be asynchronous. It's just an object constructor, it doesn't perform the `fetch()` itself.

You need to call the `req()` method with `await` to wait for the `fetch()`.

`req` also needs to be in the object that you're returning.

```js
function getAppState() {
  return {
    appState: {
      someBar: false
    },
    async req() {
      const resp = await fetch("https://www.example.com/script.php", {
        method: 'GET',
      })
      this.appState.someBar = await resp.json();
    }
  }
}
let foo = getAppState();
await foo.req();
console.log(foo.appState.someBar);
```

Comment: running this the browser throws an exception `(index):105 Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. That's for the `await foo.req();` expression.

Comment: So make the caller asynchronous.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using .then instead of awaiting promise resolution.
Like this:

```
let foo = getAppState();
foo.then(r=> console.log(r));
```

I am not aware of any other way to solve your problem other than this.